# Could we change Recommend Deletion reason to simply, "This is not an answer"?

Tags: feature-request, review

I just gave a "Recommend for Deletion" review to the answer quoted below.

> "Sorry about the editing... The Stackexchange App is a bit unhandy..."

The single line above is the complete text of the answer.

I did not consider any of the standard reasons which were provided to explain my review to be a good fit. The one which came closest was the first, "This is not an answer it is commentary on *yada yada*." (Sorry. I can't remember the full text of the sentence.)

My opinion is that this reason would be more useful if it was limited to just "This is not an answer." Examples of the most common non-answer answers could also be described in the text below the reason.

There are **LOTS** of reasons why people will post answers which don't answer the question which was asked. It seems reasonable to me to have the option of selecting a generic, bottom-line based reason when the other standard review responses are not a good fit.

If this suggested change is accepted, I would also suggest moving this reason to the bottom of the list of reasons. Putting it at the bottom may increase the probability that a reviewer would also consider the other standard reasons before choosing the most generic one.

Answer (score 2):

You can always comment in the LQ review queue and select "(don't leave comments)" bottom when recommending deletion.

This have been said several times:

**You don't need to select a comment in the LQ review queue if another comment is already in place.**

Yeah, I had to let it out.

Comment: I did not see a way to leave my own comments in this instance. There was a box for a "custom" response/reason in any item I reviewed. I looked for it in this case but did not see it. It may well be there, but I did not see it. If I had I would not have taken the time to ask this question.